# Lua: How to extract function from _G?

Tags: lua

Currently I am trying to show all of the contents stored in _G.
Reading and writing tables in _G is quite easy.

Does anyone know how to do the same with the type function?

My goal is to return a string containing a function stored in the _G table.

Cheers and thanks
Max

Comment: All functions stored in `_G` when Lua starts are C functions. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: I am trying to understand what really happens when I call a function. For example: If I execute print(Foo), why do I see the content of foo displayed. Is it possible to understand me? ;)

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate, clear question.

Answer (score 1):

The only information you can get about a function is names of its arguments (unless debug info is stripped).

```
local function print_func(func)
   local addr = tostring(func):match'%X(%x+)%X*$'
   local info, params = debug.getinfo(func, 'u'), {}
   for i = 1, info.nparams do
      params[i] = debug.getlocal(func, i)
   end
   if info.isvararg then
      params[#params+1] = '...'
   end
   print('function@'..addr..'('..table.concat(params, ', ')..')')
end

local function example(x, y) return x+y end

print(print)     --> function: 000007FEE30B6900
print(example)   --> function: 00000000005CEFD0

print_func(print)     --> function@000007FEE30B6900(...)
print_func(example)   --> function@00000000005CEFD0(x, y)
```

P.S. In some languages (e.g, Smalltalk) a function object holds its source code exposed as its property.

Comment: Hi @Egor, I just tried your code above in 5.1 on a _G function, and it returns `Runtime error: Line 4: 'for' limit must be a number`, which is this line `for i = 1, info.nparams do` - an example call I used was `print_func(gcinfo)` ? Any ideas on what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

To show all contents in `_G` you can do this:

```
for n in pairs(_G) do print(n) end
```

If you want to get only the `type` function:

```
 for n in pairs(_G) do 
     if n=="type" then
         print(n) 
     end
 end
```

You can check the output of the above [here](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

Comment: Hi, trying to clarify... check this statement: 
print(_G["print"])
This returns: function: 0x41b850

To be precise, I want to read "whats behind" this return.

Comment: You mean you want to check how `print` is implemented in lua? There is no way for you to get access to the body of a builtin function in plain Lua because the source code of `print` has already been compiled to byte-code. Of course, If you want to see the source code of `print` you can check out the `lua` `C` files found in the repo of the language.

Comment: Bad example, as I want to do the procedure you described with a function provided by a program using lua. The function is not described with builtin..., it has some kind of alphanumeric code.

Comment: Ah, I got your point now. You can use the `debug` library and its `getinfo` function for this, although I don't think you can get access to the body of the function right off the bat. `debug.getinfo` can return  a lot of useful [info](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.9) such as the `name` of the function and also the the first and last line numbers, in the source, where this function was defined. So you can use all this to write a parser to get the exact body of your function. See a relevant example [here](https://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=debug.getinfo)